# Two login page in one angular application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, architecture

As I am working on a project which requires login for different roles, like one for Consultant and other for Employee. so I have created two login pages. so is this a good idea to create two login page?

Comment: separate batches

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @PankajGadge Niiiiiice :)

Comment: Why not read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017?

Comment: I have  edited the question as it was similar to other question , please have a look in the edited one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trivial example:

```
declare @var int=1
select @var
go
declare @var int=1
select @var
```

Without GO separating the batches here, you couldn't redeclare the same variable twice

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides commands that are not Transact-SQL statements, but are recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code Editor. These commands can be used to facilitate the readability and execution of batches and scripts.

GO signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.
SYNTAX : GO [count]

count is a positive integer. The batch preceding GO will execute the specified number of times.